# Extracting data from api using powershell tool Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: json, powershell, curl

I am trying to get JSON details from an api using powershell.
I do not have any expereince with power shell, but I guess Invoke-RestMethod would be helpful.

the api I am trying to use is :

api.spotcrime.com/crimes.json?lat=30.639155&lon=-96.3647937&radius=0.02&key=spotcrime-private-api-key

Comment: Have you tried it? You should be able to see documentation by running `get-help invoke-restmethod` or search for the documentation on the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the online documentation: [Invoke-RestMethod](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx)

Here is a sample showing how to access the data returned from this API:

```
$uri = 'api.spotcrime.com/crimes.json'

$params = @{
    lat = '30.639155'
    lon = '-96.3647937'
    radius = '0.02'
    key = 'spotcrime-private-api-key'
}

$crimes = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Body $params | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty crimes

$crimes | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

In this dataset we have an object named crimes which contains an array of records. Expanding the crimes object and storing it to a `$crimes` variable will allow us to work with the records more easily.

Notice how `Invoke-RestMethod` automatically detects and converts JSON into objects. No need to use `ConvertFrom-Json`.